# Appended data to formData in node.js...the data which i am posting to my api is always showing null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, asynchronous

Recently I was trying to append a lot of HTML form values to MongoDB database through an async process

this const createproperty are my MongoDB fields which i have taken in an array

```
 const createProperty =  ['propertyType',
                      'propertyName',
                      'bhkType',
                      'ownershipType',
                      'builtUpArea',
                      'propertyAge',
                      'floorType',
                      'floorNumber',
                      'numberOfFloors',
                      'city',
                      'expectedPrice',
                  ]
```

.. these ids are some id's from the HTML form which i have put in an array

```
const myids = ['#thisPropertyType',
            '#thisPropertyName',
            '#thisBhk',
            '#thisOwnerShip',
            "#thisArea",
            '#thisAge',
            '#thisFloor',
            '#thisFloorNo',
            '#thisTotalFloor',
            '#thisCity',
            '#thisEp', ]
```

this newproperty will give me the values from the Html form, all of the values are stored in the form of an array and this for loop works just fine which gives me all the form values perfectly

```
const newProperty = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<myids.length;i++){
        newProperty[i] = $(myids[i]).val();
    }

             const form = new FormData();
            for(var i=0;i<newProperty.length;i++){
                form.append(createProperty[i],newProperty[i]);
            }
            await createData(form);
```

this is the function which follows the async process

```
       export const createData = async (data) => {
try{
    for (var value of data.values()) {
        console.log(value); 
     }
    const res = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/myapi',
        data
    });

    if(res.data.status==='success'){
       alert('success');
    }
    console.log(data);
}
catch(err){
    alert('error');
}
```

}

i console.logged the values from the createdata function, it gives me the values perfectly but it is not pushing the values to the mongodb server, when i look at the collection, there is an document which is created but it has no data in it..

please help me where have i done wrong, i'm not getting where did i go wrong..

Thank you so much for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) expect the data to be JSON object not `FormData`

This will construct the body as JSON with keys from `createProperty` array

```
const data = {};
myids.forEach((id, index) => {
    data[createProperty[index]] = $(myids[i]).val();
})
```

then you can send these values directly through `axios`

```
await createData(data)
```

Comment: i have to tell u... god is u.. thank u soo much Rami

Comment: Hello, I am trying to send images using the same code above, but somehow it is showing this error.. please can u help me..                                                                                                   error: images: Cast to [string] failed for value "[{}]" at path "images"                                                                        images is the schema field